# How to configure EXIM to check SPF record for incoming emails and add 'Received SPF' header to the incoming emails?

Tags: email, email-server, exim, spf

I'm playing with Exim and created a mail server that can accept and send emails alright. Now, I want to enable SPF checking for every incoming email so that a `Received SPF` header is added to these emails. But I can't seem to figure out a way how to do this.

The doc says, `SPF verification support is built into Exim if SUPPORT_SPF=yes is set in Local/Makefile. The support uses the libspf2 library https://www.libspf2.org/.`

But I suppose one can only set this option to yes if he/she is building Exim from source. I installed it directly from ubuntu package (I imagine libspf2 is auto-installed then) and don't know where the location of the `Local/Makefile` is. I am pretty sure this can be done pretty easily but I have no clue of this right now.

I also checked the Exim config directory and found the following relevant piece of code in `30_exim4-config_check_rcpt` file.

This clearly says, Exim will check SPF record of the sender after the RCPT command if SPF check is enabled and `spf-tools-perl` is installed. I installed `spf-tools-perl` and still did not see any `Received SPF` header. So, this begs two questions.

1. How to enable SPF checking to enable the execution of this code?
2. Why spf-tools-perl as the doc clearly says Exim uses libspf. Why two libraries then?

````
  # Use spfquery to perform a pair of SPF checks.
  #
  # This is quite costly in terms of DNS lookups (~6 lookups per mail).  Do not
  # enable if that's an issue.  Also note that if you enable this, you must
  # install "spf-tools-perl" which provides the spfquery command.
  # Missing spf-tools-perl will trigger the "Unexpected error in
  # SPF check" warning.
  .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_SPF
  deny
    message = [SPF] $sender_host_address is not allowed to send mail from \
              ${if def:sender_address_domain {$sender_address_domain}{$sender_helo_name}}.
    log_message = SPF check failed.
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    condition = ${run{/usr/bin/spfquery.mail-spf-perl --ip \
                   ${quote:$sender_host_address} --identity \
                   ${if def:sender_address_domain \
                       {--scope mfrom  --identity ${quote:$sender_address}}\
                       {--scope helo --identity ${quote:$sender_helo_name}}}}\
                   {no}{${if eq {$runrc}{1}{yes}{no}}}}

  defer
    message = Temporary DNS error while checking SPF record.  Try again later.
    !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
    condition = ${if eq {$runrc}{5}{yes}{no}}

  warn
    condition = ${if <={$runrc}{6}{yes}{no}}
    add_header = Received-SPF: ${if eq {$runrc}{0}{pass}\
                                {${if eq {$runrc}{2}{softfail}\
                                 {${if eq {$runrc}{3}{neutral}\
                  {${if eq {$runrc}{4}{permerror}\
                   {${if eq {$runrc}{6}{none}{error}}}}}}}}}\
                } client-ip=$sender_host_address; \
                ${if def:sender_address_domain \
                   {envelope-from=${sender_address}; }{}}\
                helo=$sender_helo_name

  warn
    log_message = Unexpected error in SPF check.
    condition = ${if >{$runrc}{6}{yes}{no}}
  .endif```
````

Comment: Have you figured it out eventually?